# Getting XML document schema from remote file in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xsd

Struggling to find much information on this. I’m developing an interface in PHP 5.3 where a user can enter a random .XML feed URL with an unknown structure, the next step the user has the option to decide how they want to use each of the attributes & nodes in the new XML.

Trouble is the XML files can be quite large, 50mb+.

Is there a way I can determine the document nodes/attributes/schema without downloading the complete .XML file while the user is waiting?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

By the book an XML is only complete if you have the whole document, which is then the whole file.

That is independent from [XML-Schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29) btw.. A reference to a doctype declaration or schema location reference attribute are available at the beginning of a document (if).

So with an event based parser, you can work on partial document, so to retrieve the beginning and look for schema and document type.

It would also be possible with such a praser (e.g. XMLReader in PHP) to peek into the first X bytes.